# Working with Map Fragment Activity

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm trying to create a basic activity with a google map fragment. Right now I have this:

```
public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        // add the map fragment to the activity
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
             if (savedInstanceState != null) { return; }
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .add(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentGoogle()).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FragmentGoogle extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_google, container, false);
    }
}
```

Which is producing this:

[image]

My question is: how can I interact with the fragment itself? Let's supposse I want to zoom in Sidney. Should I put the code in the MainScreen.class or in the Fragment.class? Which methods should I use? It's my first time working with fragments.

Comment: you should include your .xml too. Also, you can start from official google maps for android tutorial and plenty of free tutorials like android hive, vogella or codepath. This shouldn't be a difficult problem.

Comment: you don't need to create a class for fragment, you can directly do it from main activity class. I suggest you to try this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to create your own FragmentGoogle. You can use com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment and controll it from you activity code.

in the layout:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

and then in the Activity code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

The code is taken from
[this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_5_hello_map_take_a_look_at_the_code) which is enough to start and use most of the features of the Google Maps Android API, just follow the steps :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have an empty activity in a new project.

do this :

[creating premade android map activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXbSz.png)

And then you ll get something like this :

[your project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6mwy.png)

go to google maps api and do what they tell you to do in the (TODO)

- Create an account and a project on google maps platform https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/
- Activate android development by clicking a button you ll have to look for it
- and then go to key section to create new api key
- go back to android studio and click the yellow xml file in the picture
- past your key there

So by now the Map actvity should give you a real map and everything should work , you should see the map if you get to the map activity 

but now what you want is to add that map inside your MainActivity .(i named it ActivityMain because MapActivity and MainActivity look the same )

Now all you need to do is copy past the fragment of the xml file activity_maps.xml without changing anything except for the id .
 
this is the activity_main.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

I tried adding a button here but i couldn't.
 So what i did is copy the fragment itself and put it inside the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:gravity="center"
  tools:context=".ActivityMain">

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start" />

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

I think these are all steps to create the picture you have in your question.
I hope this was useful not painful to read .